# How write my condition when using destructuring when mapping over an Array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, conditional-statements, destructuring

I am working with the following array of objects:

```
var persons: {
    label: string;
    value: string;
}[]
```

I iterate over the array like this:

```
   {persons?.map((person) => {
      return (
        <button
          key={person.value}
          data-active={value === person.value}
        >
          {person.label}
        </button>
      );
    })}
```

Now I use destructuring so I don't have to write `person.value` etc all the time, so I don't have redundant code:

```
   {persons?.map(({ value, label }) => {
      return (
        <button
          key={value}
          // data-active={value === person.value}
        >
          {label}
        </button>
      );
    })}
```

But how do I get my boolean now `data-active={value === person.value}` (since now `{value === value}` is always true)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use destructuring, you need to avoid shadowing your existing `value` variable. You can use renaming in your destructuring pattern:

```
{persons?.map(({ value: thisValue, label }) => {
   return (
     <button
       key={thisValue}
       data-active={value === thisValue}
     >
       {label}
     </button>
   );
})}
```

...but I'd lean toward renaming your outer `value` variable instead, perhaps calling it `activeValue`. Then you don't need the renaming:

```
const activeValue = /*...*/;
// ...
{persons?.map(({ value, label }) => {
   return (
     <button
       key={value}
       data-active={activeValue === value}
     >
       {label}
     </button>
   );
})}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an [alias](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Assigning_to_new_variable_names) for `value` (I've used `v`), so the destructured `value` won't shadow the `value` from the outer scope:

```
 {persons?.map(({ value: v, label }) => {
    return (
      <button
        key={v}
        data-active={value === v}
      >
        {label}
      </button>
    );
  })}
```